# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - unable to write bytes broken pipe - Precaution

Tags: 12.04, boot, gpu-driver

I am working with **AOSP for Beagle-bone** .

During the development suddenly my PC shows an issue in booting & the message was `"unable to write bytes broken pipe"` .

I have tried lot of solutions found online & nothing works.

Now i just re-installed the OS in my PC causes waste of time & resources.

Some of the ask-Ubuntu post says that the issue is regarding the "`updation of graphic drivers`".

How can i take some precautions , in order to being safe from this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From the above error we hope so the drive which you have installed is not mounted. This might be causing the issue. So please try the below command,

```
mount -o remount,rw,errors=remount-ro /
```

After doing so please check the below,

```
dkpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Once you are done. Please restart the machine and check.